# Symfony back ground activity after to send response error session

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I'm using [Symfony 4.4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) with Redis for the session.

I have some controllers and I wish to update the DB on back ground after to send a reply to user.

So I have written a code like this:

```
class GetCatController extends AbstractController
{
    public function getCatController(LoggerInterface $logger, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, SessionInterface $session, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
       [...]
       $replyToSend =  new JsonResponse($reply, 200);
       $replyToSend->send();
       
      //My back ground activity like to do some query on the db.
        [...]

        return null;
    }
```

But I have some problems about the sessions.

Is there a better way to create and run background activity sending before the reply to user?

Answer (score 1):

There are two decent ways to do this.

If you are running PHP under php-fpm (not mod_php), you can dispatch & catch an event, [kernel.terminate](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-terminate) In Symfony pre-4.4, this is called `PostResponseEvent` (`TerminateEvent` from 4.4/5.0).

The better choice may be with [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html). Here, you would create a *message* object, with all the information needed to perform the task, and send it to a background queue (Redis is supported as a queue). A worker then consumes that message, and does the task.